# Translate from df using amazon translate and python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there any way I can translate data using amazon translate model, from specific columns of my df at once and save it in the same df in excel?
Say I have three columns from a total of 10 I want to translate data from them, can I specify that somehow and get it exported without being forced to do the translation separate for each column?

```
translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate', use_ssl=True, region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id=access,
                     aws_secret_access_key=secret)
```

df
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not provide any dataframe let's assume you have a dataframe `df` with a column called `text` where you have english text that you want to translate in french.
Using your `translate` object you can do the following:

```py
df['translated_text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: translate.translate_text(Text=x, SourceLanguageCode='en', TargetLanguageCode='fr').get('TranslatedText')
```

This will add a new column called `translated_text` with the result. Please look at [AWS SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_gb/translate/latest/dg/examples-python.html)

For a generic approach to translate multiple columns you can do:

```py
cols_to_translate = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
for col in cols_to_translate:
  df[f'translated_{col}'] = df[col].apply(lambda x: translate.translate_text(Text=x, SourceLanguageCode='en', TargetLanguageCode='fr').get('TranslatedText')
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, unfortunately I am getting this error, maybe because I don't have value on all the rows, is there a way to pass this exception: Invalid type for parameter Text, value: nan, type: <class 'float'>, valid types: <class 'str'>?   Also, the values for my  SourceLanguageCode and TargetLanguageCode are found on each row of the columns source and target in my df, since they are different for each row so it is possible to read them from there and not provide the language in the parameters? I will provide a sample in the description. Again, thank you so much

Comment: I will mark this as the right answer and open another question for my last question